# lost privileges

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

With the background update, I seem to have lost access to moderation tools, and to the ability to vote on closing questions. Was that intentional?

Comment: How tragic. For me too! Having to work all the way back upto "trusted user".

Comment: @Deepak: Yeah, I know, and with the lost 50 points it would be so much more difficult...In the meantime we'd have to withstand all those awful questions that will remain open forever, and will get more and more awful answers. Arghhh...

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- this is by design.

See

[Can we grandfather in rep abilities as sites leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta)

more detail at

https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges

Comment: Thanks. I was particularly concerned about closing questions, which now requires all (or almost all) the users with the corresponding privileges to get together and decide. There are a couple of pretty outrageous questions on the front page currently.

Comment: @moshe flag these questions for moderator attention via the flag menu

Comment: Good idea, thanks.

Comment: @Moshe: In fact, since there are only 4 non-mod users with close privileges, there is currently no way for non-mods to close a question at all. But that will change. One user is very near 3000, four more are within 600 rep of the threshold. You can help by finding good content to vote for.